# Run multiple commands when function called Bash

Tags: bash, function

UPDATE:::
In the comments, I've got an answer. Thank you!
:::

I have this sample, I want it to run multiple commands and give an output but It runs only the first command 'terraform init'. How can tell it to run all of the commands with the if statement that checks if file exists or not?

```
file = ./launchpad.yaml

function run_with_existing_config
{
  option=0
  until [ "$option" = "2" ]; do
    printf "\n ${menu} 1.) ${normal} Run your Cluster \n"
    printf "\n ${menu} 2.) ${normal} Return to the Main Menu \n"

    read -p 'Enter choice: ' option
    echo ""
    case $option in
      1 ) run_cluster ;;
      2 ) main_menu ;;
      3 ) break ;;
      * ) tput setf 2;printf "\n ${menu} Please enter ${number} 1 ${menu} or ${number} 2 \n"; tput setf 2;
    esac
  done
}

function run_cluster
{
  terraform init
    
  #terraform apply -auto-approve
  if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
    continue
  else
    mv -i ./$file ./$file.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M").yaml
  fi

  terraform output --raw mke_cluster > ./$file
  cat ./$file
  #launchpad apply
  exit 0
}
```

Comment: continue is for going to the next step in a loop.  use `bash -x yourscript args` to see each of the lines actually run ..

Comment: Thank you @MrR will know about that for the future.

Comment: Did that fix your problem, then?

Comment: Yeah it does. Thank you.